# I want to give access to the user to certain company name display using datagrid using VB.Net 2012 with sql server 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

i need to know if **already** that **user have permission mean**.. that **column** must be **checked**... i used the following codes for that..bt its not working... pls help me..
my **datagrid** name **DGV1**
  in my old version they are using list view for this.. bt i have to use datagrid.. and i also added a **datagridcheckbox** column in my datagrid names **SEL**
  so tht if the already user have permission the check box is checked already.. soo if user **uncheck** that one...the **permisson will be revoked**.. revoking the permission is working properly.. bt i cant display the user list who have grant acess for the desired company..

```
 Private Sub getuserlist()
    strCon = "Server=PTMCPC25;Database=CSSYSDB;uid=sa;pwd=Sqlsvr12"
    sqlCon = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(strCon)
    sqlCon.Open()

    coid = getcoid()
    Dim i, j, k As Integer
    Dim aruid(100) As String
    Dim count As Integer

    Dim rs4 As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * from sy30102 order by uid ", sqlCon)
    j = 0
    ' count = New DGV1.BindingContext(DGV1.DataSource, DGV1.DataMember).Count
    rs4 = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If rs4.HasRows Then
        Do While rs4.Read
            count = count + 1
            aruid(j) = rs4("uid")
            j = j + 1
        Loop
        rs4.Close()
    End If
    rs4.Close()
    ds = New DataSet
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    da = New SqlDataAdapter("Select uid 'USER ID',uname 'USER NAME' from sy30102 order by uid", sqlCon)
    ds.Clear()
    da.Fill(ds, "ConnToSqlDrp")
    If ds Is Nothing = True Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        da.Fill(ds)
        DGV1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    End If


    k = count - 1
    For i = 0 To k


        Dim rs1 As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
        Dim cmd2 As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select * from sy30103 where COYID = '" & coid & "' and UID = '" & aruid(i) & "'", sqlCon1)
        Try
            rs1 = cmd2.ExecuteReader
            If rs1.HasRows Then

                ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("SEL").value = True
                'Next
            End If
            rs1.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString())
        End Try
    Next
    closecon()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

No one made a Reply...My self i had found he solution...

Private Sub getuserlist()

```
    Try
        If cmbcname.Text <> "" Then
            For Each ROW As DataGridViewRow In DGV1.Rows

                Dim rs1 As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
                Dim cmd2 As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select * from sy30103 where COYID = '" & cmbcname.SelectedValue & "' and UID = '" & ROW.Cells("USER ID").Value.ToString & "'", sqlCon)
                Try
                    rs1 = cmd2.ExecuteReader
                    If rs1.HasRows Then
                        'For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DGV1.Rows
                        '    l = DGV1.CurrentRow.Index
                        'row.Cells("Column1").Value = True
                        ROW.Cells("SEL").Value = True
                    Else
                        ROW.Cells("SEL").Value = False
                        'Next
                    End If
                    rs1.Close()
                    'rs1 = cmd2.ExecuteReader
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString())
                End Try
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    'closecon()
End Sub
```